# Why doesn't theme('wow_'.$cloud, $output) work as expected?

Tags: theming, 7

I can't get `theme()` to work as expected. I cleared the cache, but only if I change the code to call `theme('wow_template', $output')`, it works.

```php
function wow_page() {
    $cloud = 'jqcloud';
    $output = array(
        'form' => drupal_get_form('wow_cake'),
        'words' => _wow_get_words(),
        'view' => 'wall'
    );
    switch ($cloud) {
        case 'jqcloud' :
            drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'wow') . '/js/jqcloud-1.0.3.min.js');
            break;

        case 'tagcloud' :
            drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'wow') . '/js/jquery.tagcloud.js');
            drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {$("#wow-container a").tagcloud({size:{start:20,end:40,unit:"pt"},color:{start:"#133D1D",end:"#5F614F"}});});', 'inline');
            break;
    }

    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'wow') . '/js/jquery.textlimiter.js');
    drupal_add_css('http://ca/' . drupal_get_path('module', 'wow') . '/wow.css', array('type' => 'external'));
    drupal_add_css('http://ca/' . drupal_get_path('module', 'wow') . '/fontkit/stylesheet.css', array('type' => 'external'));
    drupal_add_css('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700', array('type' => 'external'));

    return theme('wow_'.$cloud, $output);
}

function wow_page_for_word($word) {

    if ($_POST['word']) {
        $input_string = $_POST['word'];
        $output = array(
            'status' => 'false',
            'content' => array()
        );
        $word = filter_xss(drupal_strip_dangerous_protocols(check_url($_POST['word'])));
        $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
        $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node', '=')
                ->propertyCondition('status', 1, '=')
                ->propertyCondition('type', 'wall_of_words', '=')
                ->fieldCondition('body', 'value', '%' . db_like($input_string) . '%', 'LIKE');
        $result = $query->execute();
        if ($result) {
            $output['status'] = 'true';
        }
        $nodes = $result['node'];
        $fields = field_info_instances('node', 'wall_of_words');
        $field_id = $fields['body']['field_id'];
        field_attach_load('node', $nodes, FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT, array('field_id' => $field_id));
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            array_push($output['content'], $node->body['und'][0]['value']);
        }
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($output);
        exit;
    }
}

function wow_cake($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['limitedtextarea'] = array(
        '#name' => 'limitedtextarea',
        '#suffix' => '<div class="buttons">
                        <span class="wow-bottom-line">
                            <span class="count">75</span> Characters remaining </span>
                            </div>',
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#resizable' => FALSE,
        '#default_value' => '',
        '#size' => 60,
        '#maxlength' => 500,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#attributes' => array(
            'onKeyUp' => 'limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,75);',
            'onKeyDown' => 'limitText(this.form.limitedtextarea,this.form.countdown,75)'
        )
    );

    $form['countdown'] = array(
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#value' => 75,
        '#attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'hidden_value',
            'size' => '75',
        )
    );

    $form['buttons']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Send Message'),
    );
    return $form;
}

function wow_cake_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
    if (empty($form_state['values']['limitedtextarea'])) {
        form_set_error('limitedtextarea', t('Please leave a thank you message in highlighted field below.'));
    }
}

function wow_cake_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $title = check_plain($form_state['values']['limitedtextarea']);
    _wow_create_node($title, $title);
}

function _wow_create_node($title = "", $body = "", $language = LANGUAGE_NONE) {
    $node = new stdClass();
    $node->type = 'wall_of_words';
    $node->status = 0;
    $node->promote = 0;
    $node->sticky = 0;
    $node->revision = 0;
    $node->uid = 0;
    $node->language = $language;

    $node->title = $title;
    $node->body[$language][0] = array(
        'value' => $body,
        'format' => 'plain_text',
    );

    if ($node = node_submit($node)) {
        drupal_set_message(t('Thank you for your kind words!'), 'status');
        node_save($node);
    }

    return $node;
}

function _wow_get_words() {
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node', '=')
            ->propertyCondition('status', 1, '=')
            ->propertyCondition('type', 'wall_of_words', '=');
    $result = $query->execute();
    $nodes = $result['node'];

    $fields = field_info_instances('node', 'wall_of_words');
    $field_id = $fields['body']['field_id'];
    field_attach_load('node', $nodes, FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT, array('field_id' => $field_id));
    $wall = '';

    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        if (!empty($node->body['und']['0']['value'])) {
            $wall .= trim($node->body['und']['0']['value']);
            $wall .= " ";
        }
    }
    if (!empty($wall)) {
        $cloud = explode(" ", $wall);
    }

    return array_count_values($cloud);
}
```

Comment: And there's a function called `theme_wow_jqcloud()` somewhere in your code, along with a declaration of that theme item in `hook_theme()`?

Comment: No, not sure... I modified my post with the complete code.

Comment: Anything used with `theme(...)` has to be defined in [`hook_theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) - it looks like you haven't implemented that hook yet

Comment: I actually have the function in another file.. guess I just need to add another entry... argh.

Comment: There's not much point me just giving you a coded solution, as soon as you want to change anything you'll be stuck again. The best thing you can do is read the `hook_theme()` docs fully and apply what you need to your situation

Comment: Forgot to modify `hook_theme` to account for new template files.